# XCRUD PHP Joomla 3.5

Tags: php, joomla, components, crud

It is a super component called XCrud . It is a component to create a table , forms in php . The problem is that the last update was in 2015 , the product does not support Joomla 3.5. If someone did fix to component worked on this version of joomla (problems with icons , permissions , etc ) , or is there some other compoment with similar capabilities ?

http://xcrud.com/demos/index.php?page=relations&theme=default

Thanks...

Comment: The author of this application is ( was ) f0ska if he's dead ?

Comment: What xcrud has to do with Joomla. Where did you get a joomla component with xcrud? there is no such component. Joomla has its own DB management.

Comment: xcrud from here: https://codecanyon.net/item/xcrud-data-management-system-php-crud/3215400. What 's own components ( front- end) has joomla to edit the data in the db tables ?

Comment: You can use this http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/hosting-a-servers/database-management/simple-adminer . This is a joomla component to edit database from administrator.

Comment: I mean editions of their own tables, not joomla system tables..

Comment: You mean your own component. Than you can check this links 1) https://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase 2)https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase 3)https://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase

Comment: I do not want to write own component!

Comment: Sorry I am unable to understand your english or may be my english is bad, or may be i need to sleep. Anyways I hope someone else comes to your rescue.

Comment: What you do not understand? I do not want to create my component, I want to use a component that has similar capabilities like XCrud.or use XCrud in Joomla 3.5 if it's possible...

Comment: Plz check my answer. I hope I am correct this time.

Answer (score 0):

So after a long discussion I got a clue of what you need. If I am wrong please correct me. Below I will list some extensions that can help you to create forms and save in database. So you just need to define your fields i.e text field, select field, radio etc and above all they are absolutely free.

1. http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/contacts-and-feedback/forms/visforms
2. http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/contacts-and-feedback/forms/proforms-basic
3. http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/contacts-and-feedback/forms/chronoforms
4. http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/contacts-and-feedback/forms/jforms

This is not the end of list you can get many more here http://extensions.joomla.org/category/contacts-and-feedback/forms

Comment: No, I need a comprehensive tool. For now, I found this : phpgrid , it might help me .

Comment: @TomaszTomzik is there any joomla extension for phpgrid?

Comment: @TomaszTomzik But this was your question " If someone did fix to component worked on this version of joomla (problems with icons , permissions , etc ) , or is there some other compoment with similar capabilities". Specifically you wanted on Joomla i thought.

Comment: This component This is the code in PHP , which places the article by PHPDirect ....